# PHP & Regular Expressions

Tags: php, regex

I've currently got an issue.

I'm attempting to format a block of text using regular expressions, and I'll explain what I've got so far and then I'll go on to explain my problem.

I have a text file, with some narrative text.

```
VOLUME I



CHAPTER I


Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 

It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing 
Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like 
Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.


VOLUME II



CHAPTER II


Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic 
typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 

It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets 
containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop 
publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

...
...
```

It has multiple **VOLUMES** and **CHAPTERS**, and needs to be formatted by PHP to look like it does in the text file, with appropriate spacing.

First, I call this formatting function to handle some whitespacing and cleanup.

```
<?php    
function formatting($AStr)
{
    return preg_split('/[\r\n]{2,}/', trim($AStr));        
}    
?>
```

Then, I call the file and continue attempting to format.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
<body>

<h1>Jane Austen</h1>

<h2>Emma</h2>

<?php

require_once 'format.inc.php';

$p = file_get_contents('emma.txt');

$p = formatting($p);

/*
foreach ($p as $l) {
    $l = trim($l);
    preg_replace('/(VOLUME +[IVX]+)/', "jjj", $l);
    $volumePattern = '/(VOLUME +[IVX]+)/';
    $chaperPattern = '/(CHAPTER +[IVX]+)/';
    $l = str_replace("\r\n", ' ', $l);

    if (preg_match('/(VOLUME +[IVX]+)/', $l, $m)) {
        echo '<h3>' . $m[1] . '</h3>';
    }
    if (preg_match('/(CHAPTER +[IVX]+)/', $l, $m)) {
        echo '<h3>' . $m[1] . '</h3>';
    }
    preg_replace('/(VOLUME +[IVX]+)/', "jjj", $l);
    echo $l . "\n";
}*/

foreach ($p as $l) {
    //$l = trim($l);
    //$l = str_replace("[\r\n]", '\n', $l);
    if (preg_match('/[\.\w]/', $l, $m)) {
        echo "\n";
    }
    if (preg_match('/(VOLUME +[IVX]+)/', $l, $m)) {
        echo '<h3>' . $m[1] . '</h3>';
    }
    $l = preg_replace('/(VOLUME +[IVX]+)/', '', $l);
    if (preg_match('/(CHAPTER +[IVX]+)/', $l, $m)) {
        echo '<h3>' . $m[1] . '</h3>';
    }
    $l = preg_replace('/(CHAPTER +[IVX]+)/', '', $l);
    echo $l . "\n";
}


?>

</body>
</html>
```

The issue is, that I can't get the whitespace (newline) between each paragraph to print. I've tried, but I can't. I tried by using this line:

```
if (preg_match('/[\.\w]/', $l, $m)) {
            echo "\n";
        }
```

Comment: means it print only `VOLUME 1` and `CHAPTER 1` and content of chapter 1 OR repeating these same and same upto final chapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have diferrent errors, first in 'formating' function the regexp must be :

```
function formatting($AStr)
{
    return preg_split('/[\r\n]{2,}/', trim($AStr));        
}
```

after you must know that preg_replace has no variable passed by reference so you must replace your line by the return of the function :

```
foreach ($p as $l) {
    $l = trim($l);
    preg_replace('#VOLUME\s+[A-z]+#Ui', "jjj", $l);
    $l = str_replace("\r\n", ' ', $l);
    if (preg_match('/(VOLUME +[IVX]+)/', $l, $m)) {
        echo '<h3>' . $m[1] . '</h3>';
    }
    $l = preg_replace('/(VOLUME +[IVX]+)/', '', $l);
    if (preg_match('/(CHAPTER +[IVX]+)/', $l, $m)) {
        echo '<h3>' . $m[1] . '</h3>';
    }
    $l = preg_replace('/(CHAPTER +[IVX]+)/', '', $l);
    echo $l . "\n";
}
```

Comment: `[\r\n]` will match \,`r` and `n` not `\r\n`. OMG fail comment handling by SO cant add back slash in code formatting

Comment: indeed it will match |r|n and |r|r and also |n|n (replace | by slashes) because quantifier starts at 2, but you are right and that's exactly the point, because the sample contains also UNIX and WIN line returns.

Comment: Hmm it doesn't match nothing actually; using http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php with /[\r\n]{2,}/ and the text \r\n it returns an empty array. I also tried with regexpal

Comment: Is there any way I can also keep the newlines inbetween each paragraph?

Answer (score 3):

This might be massively over-simplified, but can't you just do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
<body>

<h1>AUTHOR NAME</h1>

<h2>TITLE</h2>

<?php

  $p = file_get_contents('emma.txt');
  echo preg_replace('/^\s*((?:VOLUME|CHAPTER)\s+[IVX]+)\s*$/im', '<h3>$1</h3>', $p); 

?>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

To also wrap the body paragraphs in `<p></p>` (assuming there are no new lines in a paragraph) try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
<body>

<h1>AUTHOR NAME</h1>

<h2>TITLE</h2>

<?php

  $p = file_get_contents('emma.txt');
  echo preg_replace_callback('/^\s*(?:(?P<header>(?:VOLUME|CHAPTER)\s+[IVX]+)|(?P<body>.+))\s*$/im', function($matches) {
    if (!empty($matches['body'])) {
      return '<p>'.htmlspecialchars($matches['body']).'</p>';
    } else {
      return '<h3>'.htmlspecialchars($matches['header']).'</h3>';
    }
  }, $p);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

[See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DjQArS)

Comment: +1 neat solution.  `i` for case insensitive but what for `s` and `m` in `/ism`

Comment: @diEcho They are flags: http://xregexp.com/flags/ bascially for doing global searches across all text

Comment: `i` makes it case-insensitive, `s` makes `.` match newlines (which in retrospect is not required for this) and `m` means that `^$` assertions will match any new line, not just the start/end of the subject string. http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: Is it possible to also seperate the paragraphs? For example, the end of the last paragraph reads 'vex her.' would it be possible to create new lines like the text file has?

Comment: @Andrew You mean to wrap each `\r\n\r\n` separated block that is not a volume/chapter in `<p></p>`?